# Why is res.render() not doing changing the front-end?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a form, where when submitted I would like for a success or error message to dynamically show up and indicate to the user if the form was successfully submitted. I have viewed numerous SO questions relating to res.render() not working, but none seem to be applicable to my case. The difficult thing about my situation is that I don't get any error message indicating why the res.render() is not acting as it should.

**Contact-Us.ejs:**

```
<div class="m-t-30">
                        <form id="widget-contact-form" action="send" role="form" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" aria-required="true" name="name" class="form-control required name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" aria-required="true" name="email" class="form-control required email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control required" placeholder="Enter your Subject">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                                <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="5" class="form-control required" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="hidden" id="widget-contact-form-antispam" name="antispam" value="" />
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="form-submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;Send message</button>
                        </form>                         
                        <p data-animation="fadeInDown" data-animation-delay="0" id="acknowledgement"><%- success %></p>                         
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            jQuery("#widget-contact-form").validate({                                       
                                submitHandler: function(form) {

                                    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({ });
                                }
                            });

                        </script>
                    </div>
```

**Index.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Body Parse 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/contact-us', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact-us', {success: ''});
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);  
    const ack = '<i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact form submitted and sent succesfully.';
    res.render('contact-us', {success: ack}, function() {
        console.log('we just rendered');
    });
});

var port = process.env.port || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server started on port " + port + "..."));
```

The success handler for the `res.render()` function works as it should and prints to my console, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: You do realise how AJAX works, right?

Comment: I would appreciate you telling me how AJAX works, because I am missing something here.

Comment: Just try with ` <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="form-submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;Send message</button>
                        </form>`

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by trying that.

Comment: The part you seem to be misunderstanding is AJAX is *asynchronous* in that it’s not designed to work like a typical HTTP request. Requests are run in the background and as such *will not* affect the UI at the client without some sort of manual intervention. The example from @SantoshSuryawanshi would force a typical HTTP request (non-AJAX) which would yield the type of response you are after.

Comment: I'm confused because I've viewed tutorials where upon POST requests, the front-end could be dynamically rendered using templating engines like `handlebars` and `ejs`. I've made a simple web app in the past to test this feature and it works as I expect it to.

I read up on AJAX and understand the core principles. I know I manually need to reload the web page, but wouldn't that result in me having to use `window.location` on client-side JS? I was hoping to achieve my solution using Express.

Comment: Additionally, I don't understand why my browser isn't showing me `localhost:3000/send` upon the submitting the form with the button click.

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: @ShandySulen how did you figure this out? What was your solution?