# How can I pull a JS variable into EJS theme page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ejs

This is the variable on the index.js: `/* a unique referral code the user can share */ let referral_code = shortid.generate();`

I just want to the pull it onto the index.ejs page like `$({referrer_code})` or whatever would be appropriate to then get the variable from the index.js page. I'm just having trouble with the simple task of passing the referrer_code variable into the express web page template.

A bit new to React and js and could use some guidance.

Please help me pull my basic js variable into the ejs express theme page.

All I want to do is take the variable called referral_code and place it on the page as visible html text.

The variable I'm trying to display directly in html form on the theme can be seen on the index.js page, where it says:
"let referral_code = shortid.generate();"

Here's the full index page:

```
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var shortid = require('shortid');

/* New POST route for form submissions */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  /* establish mysql connection */
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME
  });

  /* user's email address */
  let email = req.body.email;

  /* a unique referral code the user can share */
  let referral_code = shortid.generate();

  /* the referral code a user submitted (might be null) */ 
  let referrer = req.body.referrer;

  /* add user to the database with INSERT */
  let query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `referral_code`, `referrer`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  connection.query(query, [email, referral_code, referrer], (err, rows) => {
    connection.end(function() {
      if (err) return next();
      return res.send({referralCode: referral_code});
    });
  });
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's the theme page I'm trying to update. You can see in the code where I added: {referral_code} and that is where I wnat to display the referral_code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Starseeds Referral App</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>SignUp to Earn Your Free Tokens!</h1>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
    <input type="text" id=" as" placeholder="Referral code">
    <button id="submit">Sign up</button>
    <script>
      $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: '/',
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            'email': $('#email').val(),
            'referrer': $('#387jh6g').val()       
          },
          "newAffiliate" = res.referralCode,
          success: function(res) {
            alert('Your referral code is: ' + res.referralCode);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            alert(errorMessage);
          }
        });
      })
    </script>
    <H2>
      <label>Your referral code: </label>
      <span id='newAffiliate'>
        {referral_code}
      </span>
    </H2>
    <p>
      (Be sure to enter your friend's referral code so you both can get tokens.)
  </body>
</html>
```

Would also like to append url to the beggining of the code, but I'm assuming that is standard?

Thanks for taking a look to help me solve this!

Comment: you ajax looks incorrect. `"newAffiliate" = res.referralCode,` look at this line. you can review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61849747/render-output-in-ejs-file-from-ajax-post-request-using-nodejs

Comment: Yes, that was definitely incorrect. That's what I was trying to do is just pull in the variable, and not sure how...

Those references showed hot to push to JS. What I'm trying to do is pull from a js variable being created on the index.js page and just pull it onto the index.ejs page. Should be super simple, right?

When I did $({referrer_code}) it seemed to try to pull the variable but says that it's missing? So how can I  actually call that variable. There's gotta be an easy way to pass it right?

Comment: This is the variable on the index.js: `/* a unique referral code the user can share */
  let referral_code = shortid.generate();`

I just want to the pull it onto the index.ejs page like `$({referrer_code})` or whatever would be appropriate, but I'm having trouble passing the variable.

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite of what was referenced, but maybe I'll make some headway now.